# How does ArcGIS calculate distance of 2 points in custom projection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I used a software called WRF to export (lat,lon) and want to draw them in ArcGIS.
but in this software, all the coordinates are caculated under this settings: the earth is as a sphere which the radius is 6370km. 
Details:
-lambert projection:
cen_lat:24
cen_lon:115
true_lat1:4
true_lat2:44
false-easting:45000
false_northing:45000

How to set these numbers in ArcGIS if these coordinates are projected correctly and distance of these two points is the same as in that software?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a well-known text string based on the parameters you listed.

> PROJCS["WRF_Lambert_conic",GEOGCS["WRF_gcs",DATUM["WRF_datum",SPHEROID["WRF_sphere",6370000.0,0.0]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Lambert_Conformal_Conic"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",45000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",45000.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",115.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_1",4.0],PARAMETER["Standard_Parallel_2",44.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",24.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

You will need to copy this string into a text file (using Notepad.exe) and make sure there are no carriage returns within it. That is, it's needs to be on a single line, although it can have a carriage return at the end of the string.

Name the text file something like WRF_coordinate_system.prj and save it to a folder. If you're using shapefiles, you can directly copy it to the shapefile's folder and rename it as shapefile_name.prj. Otherwise, use the Define Projection tool to assign this coordinate reference system definition to the data you want to use in ArcGIS.

Note: You may get a "geographic transformation" warning in ArcMap if you're overlaying the WRF data with other datasets. You can probably ignore it. If you're reliably seeing a north-south offset in the data, try creating a custom geographic transformation using geocentric translation for the method, and zeroes for the parameters.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did work! My problem has been solved.